# Clearing a complex object

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a complex object with a couple of collections in it.
The object and collections are bound to controls in my view model.

What's the best way of clearing the object?

I don't think that I should create a new object because the view model will require rebinding.
I tried writing reflection code but it got tricky really fast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to your class, perhaps called "Clear()", that sets all member variables to null and removes all items from the lists.